# For symmetric positive definite $A,\ B$ does $\sqrt{AB}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B ∈ F$ n×n be Hermitian and positive deﬁnite and assume
that $S = AB$ is also positive deﬁnite.

Show that for the unique positive deﬁnite square roots of A, B, S, we have
$\sqrt{S} =\sqrt{AB} =\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$

This result is required to prove the next part. However, I feel that above is not correct. I tried checking it with random SPD matrices in Matlab.

My analysis shows that it is true only when $\sqrt{A},\  \sqrt{B}$ commutes?  I wonder, am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for $AB$ to be positive definite, you need $AB = (AB)^*=B^*A^*=BA$, so $A$ and $B$ commute, hence $\sqrt A$ and $\sqrt B$ also commute, and yes it is true.

Comment: why $AB$ needs to be symmetric ?

Comment: @zimbra314:  $AB$ positive definite implies $\langle ABx,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x$, which implies $\langle ABx,x\rangle$ is real for all $x$, which implies $AB$ is Hermitian. I'm assuming complex scalars.  If you are also allowing real scalars, how precisely do you define positive definite?  Typically in the real case symmetric is part of the definition, whereas in the complex case Hermitian is already a consequence of $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq 0$.

Comment: isn't $AB$ positive defintie implies $(AB+(AB)^{T})/2=(AB+BA)/2$ is positive definite?

Comment: @zimbra314: I updated my comment.  So you are asking about the real case?  Typically a positive real matrix is by definition assumed to be symmetric.

Comment: I see. Field in consideration is complex. I understand it now. Thanks so much

Comment: Why A, B commute implies their square roots commute?

Comment: @Connor: A and B are simultaneously diagonalizable because they commute, and the square roots come from taking the positive square roots of the eigenvalues, with the same eigenvectors.